# How to return a response after django form is submitted?

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms

I am new to django framework and application development. I am building an application to take some user input then process the data and save in the database.
I am using Django forms to accept some input from user and send to my views. The data sent by user will be processed in the backend and then accordingly a response will be sent to the user after processing the data.

I am able to successfully send the data from my template to the views. However, i am not getting how to send a response back to the template for user.

Any suggestions on this would be very helpful.

Comment: Please read the doc carefully. And post you code scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send back a succcess message for example, you can youse the messages framework, like:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class YouFormView(FormView, SuccessMessageMixin):
    #you cand override the method def get_success_message to do
    #a dynamic success message
    success_message = "Your message goes here"
```

And, in template, just do this:

```
    {% if messages %}
        {% for m in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                {{ m }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```